# Why does my dog drink so much right after relieving herself?

Tags: dogs, behavior

When my dog comes back in the house after relieving herself outside, she often heads directly to her water bowl to drink like a fiend. It seems logical to me if she does it on a hot day, or if she's been outside for a while. It is not limited to those cases though - it's almost as if she thinks 'Ok I'm empty, must refill as quickly as possible!'

What's going on in that crazy little head of hers?

Comment: Could just be thirsty? :D

Answer (score 1):

Our dog used to do this also. We took her to the vet and they had to run test on her. We found out she was diabetic. They told us that's the one thing to look for in pets.

**Our vet told us when the animal drinks a lot, almost like they can't get enough water, diabetes is the first thing they suspect.**

They ran blood work and found this out.  I would take her to the vet. Good luck, hopefully it's just nothing.

Comment: Ah thanks, I know that's something to watch for in humans too so that makes sense. I'll mention it during the next vet visit just to play it safe.